# Typescript & babel-plugin-module-resolver: VS Code doesn't resolve imports

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I'm currently learning to use typescript, but I have an issue with VS Code. I've set up a basic project with Babel 7 and a couple of plugins.
I run the script using the command **npm run dev**.
Here is the full list of my dependencies:

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts --extensions \".ts\" --exec babel-node"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
  "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
  "@babel/helper-plugin-utils": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions": "^7.1.0",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.2",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.1.0",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.1.0",
  "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1"
}
```

Below are the content of my 2 .ts files.

```
// src/script.ts
export default function (arg:string): string {
  return arg;
};

// src/index.ts
import Fn from "@/script";
console.log( Fn("Hello World") );
```

And here is my Babel config file:

```
//babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions"],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding"],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],//must be after @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators

    ["module-resolver", {
      //"root": ["./src", "./test"],
      "alias": {
        //"__root": ".",
        "@": "./src",
        //"#": "./src/assets",
        //"_": "./src/assets/_",
        //"!": "./static"
      },
    }]
  ]
};
```

And my Typescript config file:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@": ["./src"]
      }
  }
}
```

When I run this code, it looks good and I see "Hello World" in my console.
However, VS Code doesn't seem to understand the path *"@/script"*. It is underlined in red with a tooltip that says

> [ts] Cannot find module '@/script'.

I don't have this problem if I don't use the babel-plugin-module-resolver plugin, with the path "./script" instead.
Is there a way to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your syntax for `paths` in `tsconfig.json` is wrong.  It should be:

```
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./src/*"]
}
```

See the second example in [this section of the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping).

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot!
I reused the syntax from Babel module-resolver and I wrongly assumed that it was some kind of standard.

Comment: Mate you are awesome, thanks. React Native simply uses 'name' in package.json but for typescript to pickup in vs code I had to set this

Answer (score 1):

Based on js or ts you can add jsconfig.json / tsconfig.json in your project root.
please include below code inside.

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "@*": ["./src/*"]
        }
      }
    }
```