# How to fix TS2307 when resolving name via babel-plugin-module-resolver?

Tags: typescript, babeljs, tsconfig, typescript-module-resolution

**Issue:** We're trying to move to Typescript but absolutely stuck on: `TS2307: Cannot find module 'our-filesystem-platform' or its corresponding type declarations`.

**Context:** We have a few imports that we swap out depending on the environment, and we resolve them to the correct name using [`babel-plugin-module-resolver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver).

---

#### Our `.babelrc.js` looks like:

```js
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "our-filesystem-platform": "our-filesystem-rn",
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

#### And our `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "our-filesystem-platform": ["packages/native/our-filesystem-rn"],
    }
  }
}
```

---

I also tried `"our-filesystem-platform": ["packages/native/our-filesystem-rn/src/index"]` without any luck there either.

How can we fix this error without totally restructuring our project, or littering it with `@ts-ignore`? It seems like TypeScript demands that the resolved module name match the requested module name.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037784/typescript-babel-plugin-module-resolver-vs-code-doesnt-resolve-imports) but it's not quite the same, and we can't simply add `*` at the end of the paths to fix this.

---

The logs with TypeScript resolution tracing enabled look like:

```
======== Resolving module 'our-filesystem-platform' from '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/revisioning/src/revisioning.ts'. ========
Explicitly specified module resolution kind: 'Node16'.
File '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/revisioning/src/package.json' does not exist according to earlier cached lookups.
File '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/revisioning/package.json' exists according to earlier cached lookups.
Loading module 'our-filesystem-platform' from 'node_modules' folder, target file type 'TypeScript'.
Directory '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/revisioning/src/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/revisioning/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
File '/home/me/Documents/app/node_modules/our-filesystem-platform.ts' does not exist.
File '/home/me/Documents/app/node_modules/our-filesystem-platform.tsx' does not exist.
File '/home/me/Documents/app/node_modules/our-filesystem-platform.d.ts' does not exist.
File '/home/me/Documents/app/node_modules/@types/our-filesystem-platform.d.ts' does not exist.
Directory '/home/me/Documents/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/home/me/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/home/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
File '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/revisioning/src/package.json' does not exist according to earlier cached lookups.
File '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/revisioning/package.json' exists according to earlier cached lookups.
Loading module 'our-filesystem-platform' from 'node_modules' folder, target file type 'JavaScript'.
Directory '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/revisioning/src/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/revisioning/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/shared/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/home/me/Documents/app/packages/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
File '/home/me/Documents/app/node_modules/our-filesystem-platform.js' does not exist.
File '/home/me/Documents/app/node_modules/our-filesystem-platform.jsx' does not exist.
Directory '/home/me/Documents/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/home/me/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/home/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
======== Module name 'our-filesystem-platform' was not resolved. ========
```

Comment: The links in this answer might shed some light on the situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71544906/2954288

Comment: Thanks for the link @Harald. Honestly I don't care if it imports the types or not, I just want to build our code - which I can't as long as TS2307 is occurring.